# Ember: How to access element when action happens?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

I am new to `Ember` and I am not sure how to do things the Ember way so I turn to you.

My problem:
I have a sidebar, I created a `View` for it. I have two buttons on the sidebar for the moment. I added an `action` for each button on it. I am not sure if I should handle it on controller or on view. I want on clicking one of these button, a new view to be inserted that would open a pop up menu and also the button that called the action to remain in a selected state.

I am not very sure how to do this. I tried to target the view with the action but I can't have access to the target element or at least I don't know how to access it (tried `this.$()`).

What way do you suggest to follow?

Comment: I would maybe start here http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

Comment: @Beerlington 's recommended a link that you should read.  The Guides on emberjs.com are great.

Answer (score 1):

User 'actions' are handled with methods on a `Controller` or a `Route`.  You should put them in an `actions` hash:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        doSomething: function() {
            // do it here
        }
    }
});
```

Ember manipulates the DOM and inserts views automatically based on resources and routes.  If you don't want to use the router, you can manually control the view hierarchy, but I'd suggest getting more familiar with Ember routing before you try manual views.

If I were you, I'd create a `Component` that handled the button.  You will have a reference to the DOM element in the `didInsertElement` callback: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#event_didInsertElement